# Problems downloading CHM file from web

Tags: html, chm

My HTML is: a href="MyApp.chm">MyApp help file

When I go to this web page and click on the CHM link, the entire file is downloaded to my Downloads folder (Win10). At least the file size is identical to the uploaded file. While all the Content is visible (on the left of the CHM file) none of the CHM pages are visible. How can I see the entire CHM file? I'm guessing this is some kind of virus security.

Comment: I was wrong about the file size. The original is 807 KB while the file that was downloaded was only 303 KB. What could cause a fraction of the file to be downloaded, instead if the entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a security restrictions from Microsoft when CHM files are downloaded from the Internet.
Here is how you can fix it for this file: right click on it in Windows Explorer, click Properties, and click the unblock button.
Other possible explanations are detailed here: https://www.helpndoc.com/documentation/html/TheCHMviewerindicatesthatthepage.html